# Is there a system of three linear equations and four variables with a unique solution?

Tags: linear-algebra

In the linear algebra context, is there a system of three linear equations and four variables with a unique solution?

Comment: No, and that can be seen by considering a (reduced) row echelon form

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but how can I see it by considering a reduced row echeolon form? Do you have any example matrix?

Comment: Take any homogenous system of $3$ equations and $4$ unknowns.

Comment: when does a system of linear equations have unique solution?

Comment: First, you need at least as many equations as variables. In the case where there are exactly as many,  iff the determinant of the system is $\ne 0$. Or, if you do row reduction, there should be no free variables, and no incompatible equations of the form $0 + 0 + \cdot =$ something $\ne 0$.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!~!!~!~!

Answer (score 0):

No there should not be a system of three equations with 4 unknowns with a unique solution. In order to have a unique solution you need at least as many equations equations as variables. In your questions we have three equations and four variables which is going to leave us with one free variable when we are looking for solutions. In this situation you will be able to manipulate the 4th (or free) variable depending on what the others are to get yourself a solution.